# Testing Node app with Jasmine for status: 200

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I'm writing Jasmine tests for an app I'm building with Node.js and Express. One of the first tests is to see if the app responds with a statusCode of 200. I was working through [this tutorial](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-node-js-and-jasmine) which shows you how to do just that, but I've hit a snag.

`jasmine-node` won't run the tests. There aren't any failures; it just doesn't give a report. Apparently, [this is a known bug.](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node/issues/323)

Looking at the [jasmine-node project](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node), though, it hasn't been updated in over a year! Looking over at the main jasmine project, I see that [it now has support for Node!](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/node.html) So, has `jasmine-node` been abandoned in favor of adding support for Node into `jasmine`? After installing `jasmine` and running it against the specs, I now have a new problem. When running either `jasmine` or `npm test`, instead of getting Jasmine test failures, I get

```
Started

TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
```

Here is my spec file:

```
var request = require("request");
var base_url = "http://localhost:3000/";

describe("Hello World Server", function() {
  describe("GET /", function() {
    it("returns status code 200", function(done) {
      request.get(base_url, function(error, response, body) {
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
        done();
      });
    });

    it("returns Hello World", function(done) {
      request.get(base_url, function(error, response, body) {
        expect(body).toBe("Hello World");
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not getting a valid response.  You should check out the `error` in your callback function:

```
request.get(base_url, function(error, response, body) {

    // Check for error
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
        // Probably assert a failure here.
    }

    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
    done();
});
```

---

After inspecting the error using `console.log`, you may not want to remove the logging and replace it with some jasmine logic for error checking.